# Is there a way to spin up a new instance programmatically and direct a request there?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app which typically runs on 1 front end instance of class F1. The app receives files, saves them to blobstore, does something with them and sends them back. Sometimes the file is too large and I get

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit with 161.812 MB after servicing 1003 requests total
```

One way to solve this problem is to start running F2 instances. However, this would be a bit of an overkill because the very large files are sent once or twice a week - so the cost of running F2 would outweigh the benefit. One solution I can think of is to somehow programmatically direct all of these "receive file" requests to a new instance of its own, thereby giving it more memory to work with.

Is there a way to spin up a new instance programmatically and direct a request there?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a pretty good use-case for a '[backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview)'

Comment: Backends do work for this - I started off using them, but I am unable to only send the infrequently received "large" files there -  all received files get sent to the backend. This is problematic because a bunch of small files are received every 30 minutes and the spin up and spin down time adds an extra 15 minutes either side so this ends up as overkill and kills my usage allowance. I thus moved this operation to the front end, which works perfectly except for the large files.